# Hadoop 2.0.2 multinode cluster running issue?

Tags: hadoop

I am running a multi node hadoop 2.0.2 cluster with MRv2. My problem is at a time this particular page and fsck command only shows 3 live nodes:

[image]

Although this page shows actual no. of live nodes

[image]

Another problem is some times some datanodes are getting shutdown automatically. How can I know the pblm and why same cluster is showing two different live nodes?

Comment: That's strange. What do the log files under `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/` on your datanodes (and perhaps also on you namenode) say?

Comment: Yes, datanode log files are not showing any error in shutdown. And NameNode log file is also perfect. I run fsck command as well it also shows 3 live nodes. And these 3 live node are not constant its keep on chaining among all 7 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the web interfaces you are using `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp` is for NameNode WebUI and `http://localhost:8088/cluster` is for ResourceManager WebUI.

```
Although this page shows actual no. of live nodes
```

Actually it does not show live nodes. If you see the `Last Health Updates` for each node, you will find that three of the nodes slave-1, 2 and 3 have been updated last on 16th March 2013 and the rest have been updated last on 15th March 2013. This tallies with what you see on Namenode Interface at 50070. Only 3 are active now.

```
Another problem is some times some datanodes are getting shutdown automatically.
```

Four of your nodes went down around 01:00:00 on 15th March 2013 (last update). So I would investigate your datanode logfiles for that time as why they shut down. You can find them either inside `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/` or `/var/log/hadoop*`, if you have not set `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` environment variable

Comment: but although its showing only 3 active datanodes but more than 3 nodes are active as i checked with jps on other nodes. And the 3 active nodes get changed after some time if I refresh the page. So I am not able to figure out reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add Some configuration should be done in yarn-site.xml to let the nodemanager know where is the resource manager. Specifically, I added this property into yarn-site.xml:

`<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
  </property>`

Reason: the default value in yarn-default.xml is 0.0.0.0, and many properties use this hostname to contact resource manager, such as

`<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032</value>
</property>`